# Keep Operator alive while ending transform?

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, parent, origin

I'm trying to make a simple blender script that does the following in one click:

1. enables 'use_transform_data_origin'
2. enables 'bpy.ops.transform.translate'.
3. When 'bpy.ops.transform.translate' exited, disable 'use_transform_data_origin'

However I'm struggling to get 'use_transform_data_origin' to disable after 'bpy.ops.transform.translate' is exited. I'm not a coder by any means, but it seems like it's because finishing 'bpy.ops.transform.translate' also kills any other operators that are currently running, so the script doesn't continue.

I'm trying to keep the UX quite simple so it basically has the same experience of pressing 'G' to move an object, but for moving origins instead, with no need for the user to manually activate/deactivate the 'affect only origin' option.

The final aim is to combine this with another operator for 'affect only parent' and then (at least in my case) have shortcut 'P' activate 'Parent Move Mode' and shortcut 'Shift+P' activate 'Origin Move Mode', making those operations as simple as normal move mode. But perhaps that's not possible without building the transform operator directly into the script?

Here is the original basic script without any attempt to disable 'use_transform_data_origin' after 'bpy.ops.transform.translate' is finished. The basic script instantly disables 'use_transform_data_origin' when the user left clicks or presses space bar, but this of course also ends 'bpy.ops.transform.translate' too.

````
import bpy

class FastMoveOrigin(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.fast_move_origin"
    bl_label = "Move Origin"
    bl_description = "Move only the origin of the selected object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'LEFTMOUSE', 'SPACE'}:  # Confirm
            bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_data_origin = False
            return {'FINISHED'}
        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:  # Cancel
            bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_data_origin = False
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def execute(self, context):
        if context.selected_objects:
            bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_data_origin = True
            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            bpy.ops.transform.translate('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def move_origin_button(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator("object.fast_move_origin")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(FastMoveOrigin)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object_context_menu.prepend(move_origin_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(FastMoveOrigin)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object_context_menu.remove(move_origin_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````